# Android Studio won't run application from studio ide?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

I've got an application I've been working on and am having an issue with android studio. When I click "build->run" and then select my device, the application never runs on my phone (and the log in android-studio that automatically comes up does not have anything, whereas in the past when I have used this feature it usually says something like, "waiting for phone..." and then the application pops up and automatically opens on the phone and you get some other pertinent information). I have the phone already in developer mode with the install from unknown sources set to on. When I manually move the application from its gradle build location to the phone and then install it manually in file explorer, all is well and the application performs as expected. As I need to debug, however, this is not a very viable solution. Anybody have any advice as to how to get it to run from the IDE? I have tried rebuilding and invalidating the cache/restarting android studio, to no avail.

When I click the run tab at the bottom I have an empty window. When I click the debug tab, I see:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-samsung_sm_g920a-randomIntegerId
Uploading file
    local path: /home/eric/Documents/class/OOSE/final_project/2015-group-17/project_code/android/Place2B/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/oose2017.myApp
```

Note: I am building the application on a LUbuntu 15.04 VM on a windows 8 host, and am using the latest version of android studio.

EDIT: gradle console indicates a successful build as well (obviously since moving the .apk manually to the device works properly).

Comment: Having this same issue right now, trying to push a release apk to a Nexus 5X. I've also restarted both Android Studio & the device, nothing. Please let us know if you find a solution. What version of gradle are you using? I'm using 1.5.0

Comment: was using same as yourself. i did not find a solution unfortunately; ended up switching to windows OS for android dev, which is quite unfortunate bc developing with windows OS <<

Answer (score 4):

Open 'Run->Edit Configurations...', and look for your app module in the column on the left-hand side.

Select it, then go to the 'General' tab.

Under the 'Activity' section, there are a couple of radio buttons. Make sure that 'Launch default activity' is selected.

Comment: this option is indeed selected by default

Comment: amazing, this option was suddenly deselected after update to Dolphin, this 7 year old answer fixed it.

Comment: @de. Awesome! What a pleasant surprise to log in and see your comment. Glad it helped.